# On-topic page is still "Being Nice"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

This is actually a small update. While I was reading the help center article [What topics can I ask here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I found out that off-topic reasons are also mentioned in the same article under the heading "**What questions are off topic here?**".

Under other reasons reason, in the second bullet point, there is a mention of "Be Nice" policy.

> violate the Stack Exchange **“Be Nice”** rules by encouraging bigotry of any kind, harassment, or abuse of others. While not all interpersonal interactions meet these guidelines, our goals are to encourage respectful interpersonal skills.

For the new comers who don't know, Be Nice was the set of etiquette to be followed on the Stack Exchange Network before new [Code of Conduct](/help/Conduct) came into force.

It has been a while since Code of Conduct has replaced old "Be Nice". So, can this page also be updated?

Comment: we should definitely do that sometime in like 6 - 8 minutes :)